# How to check if the user has already logged in Unity App

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine

I am using Facebook Login and Native Email Registration/Login for a new App in Unity. Checking the login state for Facebook was easier with the SDK, using `FB.IsLoggedIn`. But, here I am trying to check if the user has logged in into the app already using the Native Email Login, and if a user has already logged in then s/he don't have to login every time.

I am able to login to the app, back-end for the app is a Node Server, from where I get `user` and `token` as return when one logs in successfully, this is done using `passport-local`. This token is used every time as authentication token to play game and to perform other options, but to use all functions a user has to login. I couldn't figure out how to handle these states in Unity.

```
{
  "user": "luzan@email.com,
  "token": "sometoken"
}
```

**Using PlayerPrefs** I read some Q&As on storing data on `PlayerPrefs`, and most of them mentioned that this might be a wrong choice to store on `PlayerPrefs`, as this is easily modifiable.

**My thoughts on this**, I was also thinking of handling it from the Node Server itself, as this is my current mongodb document for account,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e73931c2369f1bd8c89ebd"),
    "salt" : "saltkey",
    "hash" : "somehashkey",
    "username" : "luzan@email.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I was thinking of adding another field (say) `_isLoggedIn` to the MongoDB schema with the `boolean` value, that is set to `true` if the player has loggedin once and has not log out from the app. And check that every time to see if player has already logged in or not. But again, to access that document through API, I'll be needing the same token to be passed with API. And I am still confused if that `token` should be saved on `PlayerPrefs`.

Can anyone help me out here with ideas or code structure?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, your problem is to know at a given time if your user is logged in or not if so,

According to the documentation [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users)

It's recommended that you get the current user by setting a listener on the Auth object

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;



 // Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
    void InitializeFirebase() {
      Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");
      auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
      auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
      AuthStateChanged(this, null);
    }

// Track state changes of the auth object.
    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) {
        if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
            bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            if (!signedIn && user != null) {
              Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
            }
            user = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn) {
              Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
      auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
      auth = null;
    }
```

and you can get the user profile as follows

```
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      string name = user.DisplayName;
      string email = user.Email;
      System.Uri photo_url = user.PhotoUrl;
      // The user's Id, unique to the Firebase project.
      // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend     server, if you
      // have one; use User.TokenAsync() instead.
      string uid = user.UserId;
    }
```

i don't know if the user profile is preserved when the app is closed or not,So check it out.

Comment: It is a NodeJS Backend, not Firebase. Thanks for your time anyway.